# How to write a simple hello world program in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking all over the world.

All I see is samples alerting hello world

I don't want to alert hello world.

I want to print a simple website saying hello world.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body id="home">
    <script>
        //print hello world
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does javascript have a print command?

Here are typical samples on the web

http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/javascript/hellow.html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought that as well, but it doesn't make the *website* print hello world ;).

Comment: JS: `document.getElementById('home').textContent = 'hello world';` jQ: `$(function() { $('#home').text('hello world'); });`

Comment: `console.log` is that you want to get accustomed to for testing purposes. There is no 'printing' on the page as the page itself consists of elements which you need to refer to.

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/hello-world

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "print" - for most people "print" means, "send to a printer", which doesn't seem likely.  Every language uses a different term for what(whatever) you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS code you don't 'print' to the screen. Instead you amend the properties of the HTML elements in the DOM.

To do what you require you can retrieve the `#home` element then set its text. Either of the below will work for you:

```
// POJS
document.getElementById('home').textContent = 'hello world';

// jQuery
$(function() {  
    $('#home').text('hello world'); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body id="home">
    <script>
        document.getElementById('home').textContent = 'hello world';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could append a [Text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) to the body.

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World!'));
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript Write some text directly to the HTML document Use `document.write();`.

like below.

```
<script>
document.write("Hello World!");
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.write("Hello World!");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this may work, using `document.write` is considered extremely bad practice. I really wouldn't recommend it - especially to a beginner.

Comment: Its terrible and should pretty much never be used but I guess this is still the correct answer to the question asked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
document.write("hello world");
```

but I will not recommend it (for more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)).

You can use this instead:

```js
document.getElementById("home").textContent = "hello world";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log("Hello World!")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.